# How can I have a class only run on certain API levels?

Tags: android

I'm building a call blocking app that uses Itelephony to block calls. I want my app to work on API levels starting at API 16. In order for my App to work on current API levels, I need to use CallScreeningService to screen phone calls. The issue is that CallScreeningService only works on API levels 24 and up. How can I make it so Itelephony blocks call for API level below 24 and this class blocks calls for API levels 24 and up?

```
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.telecom.CallScreeningService;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallScreenService extends CallScreeningService {
    private static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
        CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
        Log.e("CallBouncer", "Call screening service triggered");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: How do you use CallScreeningService from MainActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit `Alt + Enter` (on a Mac) on the error to get a quick fix to your issue like this:

[image: Quick Fix]

Here you see that you can fix the issue by using one of two annotations.

The `@RequiresApi` marks the class as having to be run on a specific API level or above, despite your min sdk level.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class CallScreenService extends CallScreeningService {
    private static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails) {
        CallResponse.Builder response = new CallResponse.Builder();
        Log.e("CallBouncer", "Call screening service triggered");
    }
}
```

This will cause a build error if you try to use it outside of a version check.

[image: Version Check Warning]

Then you can do conditional version checking to use your new class or the old one.

[image: Version Check Passes]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){
  //do the thing that requires SDK 24 and greater
else{
  //do the thing that requires less than SDK 24
}
```

[SDK_INT documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

SDK_INT is the SDK version of the software currently running on this hardware device. This value never changes while a device is booted, but it may increase when the hardware manufacturer provides an OTA update.

Here is a link to all the SDK codes:

[SDK Version Codes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

Comment: I've used this before to avoid executing code, but as far as I know this doesn't apply to classes as I can't put this around a class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do.  This wouldn't go around the class, the class would be instantiated and it's members called from within the if/else blocks

Comment: Basically, there is a why to block calls in earlier API levels that doesn't work in later ones. I solution to blocking calls in later APIs is to use CallScreeningService which is introduced in API 24. However, in order to widen the audience that can use my app, I want to still support the old way of blocking calls. For this new way of blocking calls, I need to create a class that extends CallScreeningService, something that can only be done in API 24 >=, so I get some errors since the minimum API level is 16. I can't put if statements around a class.